# Disable high DPI scaling in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, high-dpi

Is there any way to disable the High DPI scaling of Microsoft Edge?

That UI looks awfully big if my DPI is set for 125%.
I have it disabled on Chrome and Firefox. But this may be the only thing preventing me from using Microsoft Edge.

As expected, changing the compatibility settings for the executables (MicrosoftEdge.exe and MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe) doesn't work. But is there another workaround?